# CSS - How to use pseudo elements on a Input slider button / How to set a pseudo element on a pseudo element

Tags: html, css, slider, pseudo-element

I need to create a slider with a certain style. The button on top of the slider needs to have a round circle in the center of it. In order to do so I tried to use the `::before` pseudo element.

But I have a problem in order to get this to work. I think the problem is by setting a pseudo element on top of a pseudo element. But I have no other idea how to achieve this type of button.

I have added a finale design in the snippet bellow the slider:

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1rem;
  background: #176D8A;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  position: relative;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
  content: "";
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  background: #176D8A;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb::before {
  content: "";
  
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  background: #176D8A;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test{
  position: relative;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

.test::before {
  content: "";
  
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  background: #176D8A;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">

<div class="test">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use pseudo element so put all the style on the thumb

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1rem;
  background: #176D8A;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side,#176D8A .25em,#fff .26em);
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  position: relative;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side,#176D8A .25em,#fff .26em);
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">

<div class="test">
</div>
```